# Pen color/style

Tags: c++, gdi+

In C# I define a pen using the following line, but I'm unable to set something similar in C++. I tried several options in C++ to select the `Color` object but no luck so far. I am mainly interested in selecting the color - `Color.DarkGray` - don't want to specify my own ARGB values.

```
var pen = new Pen(Color.DarkGray) { DashStyle = DashStyle.DashDot };
```

In C++ I can define like this but wanted to know if I can define with the mode `Color.DarkGray` directly instead of RGB values.

```
Pen pen(Color(255,169,169,169),1);  //DarkGray
pen.SetDashStyle(DashStyleDashDot);
```

Comment: [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) No.

Comment: Predefined color names is a feature only of .NET.  C++ programmers wouldn't recognize Teal if the wall they run into was painted that color, they use numbers.  Use the Reference Source or a decompiler to see those numbers.

Comment: Hans - thanks for your reply. I am hard-coding the values as well now in C++. Would continue this way until can find any other elegant option to define the ARGB color reference that I can use directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors are defined exactly the same in C++ as they are in C# (AFIAK, the C# System.Graphics is just a wrapper on the C++ functions anyway). All you need to do is :

```
Pen pen(Color::DarkGray, 1);
pen.SetDashStyle(DashStyleDashDot);
```

Isn't that what you're trying to do? The colors are all defined in GdiPlusColor.h if you want the full list, but it's just the same as the C# version I think.

Comment: Thank you Redeye. Yes - Your solution is perfect !!